# Is it possible to create Service account and get p12 key programmatically for google accounts?

Tags: google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, service-accounts, google-developers-console

I need to extract Google Analytics data through it's API. However I do not want to generate any account and key manually (the reason is I do not want to let this technical this to be performed by any non-techie person) and want to dump that data for analysis purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use any of Googles APIs they need to know who you are.  You as a developer are identified by the project you create on Google Developer console. Once the project is created you can create a number of different types of credentials including Service account credentials and Oauth2 Credentials.

**Answer**: No there is no way to programmaticlly create service account credentials. Nor is it possible to use the a Google api without first creating a project on Google developer console.

*Note:  [Google Cloud Resource Manager](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/) does exist but is very limited in what it allows you to do.*

If someone else is going to be running your application to access their Google analytics Data you should idealy be using Oauth2 in your application and not a service account.

Service accounts are designed as way for the developer to grant others access to data owned by the developer in question.   They are not really intended for novice users to be creating their own projects on google developer console and generating credentials.

Comment: Great! Thanks! @DaImTo for your attention, suggestions and answer :) Now there are too many questions buzzing my mind... One is **How can i automate the process or reduce manual steps (i.e. Generating client secrets or enabling APIs, allowing client-ids to access data by just prompting login pop-up)** for fetching the data periodically without any manual intervention. I am surprised because [compass.co](https://www.compass.co) is asking for just account login in order to get analytics data (GA will be plugged in compass.co account)... and that's it, i get reports.

Comment: Prompting for login is Oauth2 once the user authenticates you save the refresh token and you can access their data anytime you need.     Unless you are creating more then one application I am not sure why you would need to automate the process of generating projects.    You might want to try reading though my Google development tutorial series   http://www.daimto.com/google-development-beginners/

Comment: Okay, @DaImTo so now the question is, [compass.co](https://www.compass.co/) is the applcation which ask only for the google account login only to fetch google analytics data (I had tried it under free account)... and nothing other information i had supplied... like **client id, client secret** even though it is able to get the GA data. How is it works?

Comment: That's as it should be the developer of that application has included it in their project you as the user of their application should not see that.

Comment: Thanks, @DaImTo I debugged [compass.co](https://www.compass.co/) Now if i am not wrong... **They are using their Client ID and Secrets and get the Access Token and Refresh Token of my gmail account** in order to fetch the data and will store the refresh token to get the fresh data periodically. And this is how OAuth 2.0 can work. Please correct me if am going in wrong directions. :)

Comment: Your getting it :)   All client id and secret do is identify an application to Google.  When you authenticate an application it pops up and says application X would like to access your Y data.  If you say yes then Application X gets a refresh token granting it permission to access your Y data.    Welcome to the world of OAUTH2

Comment: Thnaks a lot man!, You are the kik start for me :) Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking if you can obtain the credentials necessary to query the API via the API. This does not work.

I am also not sure how this would help you. Before you can do any API operations to a Google Analytics account you need to have an authorized user (e.g. a service account) added to your view or property. If you are in a situation where you can add a user programmatically to an account you might as well just read the data you need.

Comment: Thanks, @Eike Pierstorff for attention and answer. Yes, eventually i am looking for the process which can Automate the OAuth 2.0 Authentication workflow.